# Python Pickling variables only in superclass

Tags: python

How do I pickle a subclass of an object but only capture the variables of its super class (and convert object to superclass).

The reason I am doing this is because I have extra information that I need to create my "class" but need a light weight version when I am reading it.

Example:

```
import cPickle
def unpickle_me(filename):
    myobj= cPickle.load( open( filename, "rb" ) )
    return myobj

def pickle_me(obj, filename):
    cPickle.dump(obj, open( filename, "wb" ) )

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []

    def read_index(self, index):
        return self.a[index]

class B(A): 
    def __init__(self, b):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = b; # let b = 3 for example

    def add_to_super(self, avar):
        self.a.append(avar*self.b)

classB = B(3)
classB.add_to_super(5)
pickle_me(classB, 'me_b.pickle')
myobj = unpickle_me('me_b.pickle')
print(type(myobj), myobj.__dict__) 
>>>> (<class '__main__.B'>, {'a': [15], 'b': 3})
```

So pickling works! And it pickles what I expect.  But in reality, I would want something more like:

```
pickle_me(classB, 'me_b.pickle')
myobj = unpickle_me('me_b.pickle')
print(type(myobj), myobj.__dict__)
>>>> (<class '__main__.A'>, {'a': [15]})  # class A and only has A
```

And as a bonus, whoever opens it cannot "append" another value to A though my "add_to_super".

Questions:
1. Is there a way to do this?  I am open to writing __ getstate __ information in both class A and class B.

1. If I use __ getstate __ , is there a way to automatically only save the variables I assign in class A?  So I don't need to say del self. __ dict __ ['b']
2. Can I write a special method that allows me CHOOSE which version I want?, like pickle only A information or pickle B information (when given a class B)
3. Side question:  do i need to define __ setstate __ in this case?  or use __ getstate __ by itself?
4. Also i realize the structure here for OO sucks, and wouldn't mind any pointers on that.

Comment: I have a pointer on the OOP - Judging by your `print` syntax, you are using Python 3.x.  In Python 3.x., there is no need to have classes inherit from `object`.  You only did that in Python 2.x. to make the classes "new-style" classes.  In Python 3.x. however, _all_ classes are "new-style".

Comment: @iCodez - `cPickle` on the other hand would suggest python2

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution would be to convert `B` into an `A` before pickling it (if you want to pickle only `A` information).

```
class B(A):
    def to_A(self):
        a = A()
        a.a = self.a
        return a
```

Then, when you unpickle this, you'll get an `A` as you wanted.

To me, explicit solution like this is better than writing a fancy pickling interface.

Regarding your point #4 (OO structure), your `B` class is called a *factory*.  Usually, it is convenient for factories to have an API of the sort:

```
factory = MyFactory()
factory.set_some_parameters(...)
factory.set_some_other_parameters(...)
A1 = factory.construct_A()
A2 = factory.construct_A()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Q4!  I'm glad it's somewhat(?) standard practice!  However, just to reiterate question 1, is there a way in my "construct_A()" to automatically detect the variables specific to only class A, so I don't need to do "a.a = self.a" and if I add more variables "a.a1 = self.a1" to set those variables?

Comment: my new version does:

    def convert_to_superclass(self):
        save_obj = self.__class__.__base__()
        for key in save_obj.__dict__.keys():
            save_obj.__dict__ = self.__dict__[key]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`__reduce__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) protocol to specify what will be pickled instead of an instance of your class, `__setstate__` and `__getstate__` always operate on the original class. So if you want to pickle a instance of `A` whenever you have an instance of `B`, it could look like this:

```
class B(A): 
    def __init__(self, b):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = b; # let b = 3 for example

    def add_to_super(self, avar):
        self.a.append(avar*self.b)

    def __reduce__(self):
        return A, (), {'a': self.a}
```

Comment: in this case, I need to specifically tell reduce what variables to save?  Is there a quick way to only grab variables in the superclass? Say if I add a variable in to class A, it is "automatically" stuck in reduce here.

Comment: No, that's not possible. `a` in this case is an instance variable, and instance variables don't 'belong' to any class, they belong to the instance. It doesn't matter that it's created in `A.__init__`, in the end it's just another entry in the instances's `__dict__`.